# MongoDB "The dollar ($) prefixed field is not valid for storage."

Tags: node.js, mongodb

While storing the key which have Dollar($) prefixed key is throwing error as "The dollar ($) prefixed field is not valid for storage." in MongoDB.

I am using MongoDB version 4.2 and NodeJS MongonDB Driver 3.5.9.

Example Snippet

```
db.collection.updateOne({_id: 'ObjectId("618bb1ccd7b16e4232dcb4e8")'}, {$set: {'$name': 'Alex'}}, {upsert: true, checkKeys: false})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mongodb 4.0 doesn't support top level field with dollar sign. You can upgrade to mongodb 5.0

https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/core/document/#field-names

Answer (score 1):

You just flat out have a syntax error, from the update [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/), the update document

> Contains only update operator expressions.

In your case you want to be using `$set`, like so:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
  {_id: 'ObjectId("618bb1ccd7b16e4232dcb4e8")'},
  { $set: { name: 'Alex'} },
  {upsert: true, checkKeys: false}
)
```

Comment: I am already using $set, it was just I didn't mentioned in the description. I have updated the description.

Comment: So instead of "$name" write "name"?

Comment: Those keys comes on the fly. I don't have control on that.

Answer (score 0):

maybe check in the mongodb file explorer if the object has a `$` anywhere?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Didn't get that